# How can I change mouse sensitivity permanently with xset?

Tags: 12.10, mouse

I know I can use xset m 3 1   to change the sensitivity of the mouse but when I turn off my computer it will go back to normal. Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to make it permanant.
There should already be settings for mice in there (see below), you would just need to change the acceleration options.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationNumerator" "1"
    Option "AccelerationDenominator" "1"
    Option "AccelerationThreshold" "0"
EndSection
```